# Why is this laplace identity true $\int_{\Bbb{R}^+}\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt = \int_{\Bbb{R}^+}\mathcal{L}\{f\}$?

Tags: integration, functions, transformation, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

I was wondering why this laplace identity is true? Does it follow from definition?
$$\int_{\Bbb{R}^+}\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt = \int_{\Bbb{R}^+}\mathcal{L}\{f\}$$

I'm trying to understand the first solution here [how do you do this integral from fourier transform.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334127/how-do-you-do-this-integral-from-fourier-transform) I don't see where the identity comes from

Comment: No, take $f(t)=t$.  Then $t/t=1$, and the integral on the left clearly diverges, but $\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s)=\frac{1}{s^2}$, so the integral on the right converges.

Comment: Say f(t)=sin(t) would the identity hold then? @Hayden

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the first solution here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334127/how-do-you-do-this-integral-from-fourier-transform I don't see where the identity comes from @Hayden

Comment: @TheProblem If you take a look at the wikipedia article, it gives you an idea of when it does hold.  But yes, it does hold for $f(t)=\sin(t)$.

Comment: @xpaul No, that is not the identity the OP seems to be referencing (just take a look at the referenced question).

Comment: Thanks, whereabouts on the article? @Hayden

Comment: @TheProblem Here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems at the section "Evaluating Improper Integrals"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you can use this in the proof:
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-st}dt=\frac{1}{s}, s>0. $$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\infty\frac{f(t)}{t}dt
&=&\int_0^\infty f(t)\int_0^\infty e^{-st}ds\,dt\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-st} f(t)\,dt\,ds\\
&=&\int_0^\infty L\{f(t)\}ds.
\end{eqnarray}
Done.